# Sumif Function Dynamic

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble writing a VBA code that will sum a column from one workbook to another based on multiple IDs. The data is setup like below.
I want workbook 2 to read the id column of workbook 1 and sum that value column.

```
WORKBOOK 1
ID     |    VALUE
2454         10
6333          5
3345         10
5667         20



Workbook 2
ID 1  | ID2  | ID 3 | ID 4  |  Sum Value    
2454   6333    3345    5667       45
```

I'm thinking I could use something like this:

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("workbook 2 sum value column")
Rng.Formula = "=SUMIF(workbook 1 ID column,workbook 2 ID 1,workbook 1 VALUE column)"
Rng.Value = Rng.Value
```

But I think I would have to repeat this code for every row and every ID in workbook 2?

I'm very new to this, and it's a little advanced for me. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a loop, and call each ID in turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following array formula works:

```
=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$4=A8:D8,$B$1:$B$4))
```

[image]

Make sure to press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` before exiting the cell. Then drag down for the rest of the columns. It will even work if some of your columns on sheet 2 have more/less ids. No need for VBA, but if you need to have for other reasons, you can apply this formula directly into the code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand that I can do this as a regular excel formula, having 100 rows of this formula really slows down my workbook. And I'll always have a new workbook 1 and a template of workbook 2 to transfer between.

Comment: so, in the vba code you can **1)** turn calcs off **2)** place this formula **3)** calculate **4)** hard code the values **5)** turn calcs back on

Comment: Or use Evaluate in VBA: myvar = [SUM(IF(A1:A4=A7:D7,B1:B4))]